# WordPress Count Taxonomy Posts + Filters

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to count taxonomy posts by those filters:

- "show" post type only
- Custom field of "done" value = no
- Taxonomy "comedian", Term ID 2 only

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'show',
   'meta_key' => 'done',
   'meta_value' => 'no',
   'taxonomy' => 'comedian',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => '2',
);
$myquery = new WP_Query($args);

echo "Found: $myquery->found_posts";
?>
```

This code filter well "shows", "done" and "comedian" **but its not filter for Term ID 2 only...** What I did wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) you should have something like this:

```php
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'show',
   'meta_key' => 'done',
   'meta_value' => ''.$overyet.'',
   'tax_query` => array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'comedian',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => 2
                  )
);
```

Comment: Still the same, It shows me the count without terms 2 filter.